# Laravel 4 - How to display a page's contents after selecting from navbar?

Tags: php, view, laravel

How do you display a post after selecting it from a nav bar? Right now I have my post linked to subjects in my navbar. I want to have the user select on the page from the navbar and have it display on the same page.

The subjects and pages are populating the navbar but am at a loss for the next steps on how to display this into the view on the same page. Currently, I have the page's contents echoed out, but it's not linked to the specific page being selected by the user.

**Route**

```
Route::resource('index', 'PublicController');
```

**View: index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Development Blog</title>
    {{ HTML::style('css/public.css') }}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Development Blog</h1>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="navigation">
            <br>

        @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $subject->menu_name }} </td><br>
            </tr>

            @foreach ($subject->pages as $page)
            <tr>
                <li><a href="{{ route('index.show', $page->menu_name) }}">{{ $page->menu_name }}</a></li><br>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
        </div>

        <div id="page">
            Content:
            <div class="view-content">
                @foreach ($subject->pages as $page)

                    {{ $page->content }}

                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<div id="footer">Copyright {{ date("Y") }}, Development Blog</div>


</body>
    </html>
```

**Controller: PublicController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all subjects
    // $subjects = Subjects::all();
    // $subjects = Subjects::with('pages')->get();
    $pages = Pages::all();

    // Load the view and pass in the subjects
    // return View::make('index')->with('subjects', $subjects)->with('pages', $pages);
    // return View::make('index', compact('subjects', 'pages'));
    return View::make('index')->withSubjects( Subjects::with('Pages')->get());
}

 public function show($slug)
{
    $page = Pages::where('slug', '=', $slug);

    return View::make('index', compact('page'));
}
```

Comment: Show me, how the route/resource for page is registered.

Comment: Edited with the route, controller was already posted.

Comment: @Andreyco Did I miss something from your previous solution? I noticed you took it down?